# Showing that $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}z^{n+2k}}{k!(n+k)!}2^{n+2k}$ Is Entire?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

In Function Theory of a Complex Variable I'm having trouble verifying my proof in $\text{Proposition (1.0)}$ specifically on how $J_{n}$ is entire on $\mathbb{C}$

$\text{Proposition (1.0)}$

For fixed $n \geq 0$ define the function $J_{n}(z)$ by the power series in $(1.0)$

$(1.0)$

$$J_{n}(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}z^{n+2k}}{k!(n+k)!}2^{n+2k}.$$

Show that $J_{n}(z)$ is an entire function. Show that $w=J_{n}(z)$ satisfies the differential equation in $(1.2)$

$(1.2)$

$$w''+\frac{1}{z}+(1-\frac{n^{2}}{z^{2}})w=0.$$

$\text{Lemma 1.3}$

Let there exist a Open Set $\Psi$, such that $\Psi \subset \mathbb{C}$ and that $J_{n}:\Psi \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, also we pick a compact subset $K$ such that $K \subset \Psi$ also note that $J_{n}:K \rightarrow U$, since $K \subset \Psi$.

$\text{Lemma 1.4}$

Every entire function $f(z)$ can be represented as a power series:

$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}z^{n}$$

that converges everywhere in the $\mathbb{C}$, hence uniformly on compact sets. The radius of convergence is infinite, which implies that in $(1.5)$ or $(1.6)$

$(1.5)$

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}|a_{n}|^{\frac{1}{n}} = 0$$

$(1.6)$

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{ln|a_{n}}{n}| = -\infty$$

$\text{Lemma (1.5)}$

For each fixed $n \geq 0$  we have  such that due to $(1.5)$ the following developments in $(1.7)$

$(1.7)$

$$\left|\frac{(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty
}(-1))^{k} \cdot (\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}z)^{n+2k}}{(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}k!) \cdot (\lim_{n \rightarrow\infty}(n+k)!)}\cdot (\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}(2))^{n+2k}\right|^{\frac{1}{n}}= 0$$

$$\left|\frac{(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty
}(-1))^{k} \cdot (\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}z)^{n+2k}}{(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}k!) \cdot (((\lim_{n \rightarrow\infty}(n)) +(\lim_{n \rightarrow\infty}(k)))!  }\cdot (\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(2))^{n+2k}\right|^{\frac{1}{n}}= |\frac{z^{3}}{k! \cdot k(\infty)}| = 0$$

$\text{Conclusion}$

Due to $J_{n}$ satisfying the condition given $(1.5)$ $J_{n}$ is entire since it converges everywhere on $\mathbb{C}$ which implies uniform convergence for our compact subset $K$.

Comment: Bessel functions of the first kind are blatantly entire since for any $k$, as $n\to +\infty$ the term $n!(n+k)!$ goes to $+\infty$ incredibly fast. Additionally, such functions are given by Fourier transforms of compact-supported functions, hence they are entire functions as a consequence of the Paley-Wiener theorem, too.

Comment: Is my initial proof wrong, or is their a better way of showing that Bessel functions of the first kind are entire with relying on the use of $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}|a_{n}|^{\frac{1}{n}} = 0$ also should I have proved that limit existed ?

Comment: I would say that zero exists :D

Comment: All right you had me scared there for a second I thought I did something horribly wrong :>(, also what's another way to prove this I've never had the chance to play with Fourier Transforms.

Comment: The Fourier transform of $J_0(x)$ is a multiple of $\frac{\mathbb{1}_{(-1,1)}(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$, you can prove this by applying $\mathcal{F}$ to the differential equation, for instance. Then have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Wiener_theorem

Comment: A very interesting exercise is to prove that $J_0(z)$ only has real zeroes (this is a sort of baby-RH for dummies).